# ros::ok() within pthread

Tags: ros, threads

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am have a couple of threads that run in a node.  The threads have a while(ros::ok()) infinite loop inside.  The problem is that when I Ctrl-C my program, it has to escalate to a SIGTERM because the ros::ok() variable never goes false.  I also tried the ros::isShuttingDown() variable and this never goes true.

How should I handle the pthreads so that they exit when the rest of the program exits?

I launch threads with:

```
pthread_t thread1
pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,thread1Function,NULL);
```

My thread function looks something like this:

```
void *thread1Function(void *obj)
{
ros::Rate loop_rate(1);

while(ros::ok())
{
//Do stuff
loop_rate.sleep();
ros::spinOnce();
}

pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The loop never exits.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12939/ros::ok()-within-pthread/) by [rplankenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/1757/rplankenhorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2012-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alright I figured it out.  I had GDB enabled for the module and it for some reason wasn't killing the threads.  As soon as I disabled it in my launch file, the threads get killed when I Ctrl-C the program.  Thanks for the suggestions.

---

Originally posted by [rplankenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/1757/rplankenhorn/) with karma: 48 on 2012-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've never had a problem running ROS with threads. Are you calling ros::spinOnce() to poll for updates?

I've never used `pthread`, but I know for a fact that it works with `boost::thread`. I know that doesn't solve your issue, but it's something to consider. But since it's really just a nice wrapper for `pthreads` on *Nix systems, it doesn't really explain the problem.

**EDIT**:

Try passing a `this` pointer to `pthread_create()`. Since the `ros::init()` is called in the parent class, you need to have access to the ROS variables in your thread.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rplankenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/1757/rplankenhorn/) on 2012-02-09**:
See my sample code above.